# Do Atoms, HEVENT, and the HBITMP or HICON created with LoadImage automatically close when process closes?

Tags: winapi, mfc, bcg

I know memory leaks from allocations through `malloc` or `new` are cleaned up when a `process` exits as are `file handles`.   But the question is are things like the `HBITMAP` / `HICON` handles loaded with `LoadImage` closed as well (not using `LR_SHARED`).

Reason I ask is because when I run deleaker on a `MFC` app using `BCGControlBarPro` it always find several leaks of Atom's, Event Handles and a HICON/HCURSOR type.  Most from MFC and some from BCDControlBarPro.  For example the HCURSOR leak is from load image in `CBCGPGlobalUtils::GetStretchCursor()`.  They are initialized one time so it looks like they presume that it does close them, I just want to be sure because I thought resources were different?

TIA!!

Comment: yes, all gdi resourses also will be destroyed when process exit

Comment: All memory/resources that are created and stored *within the process* are reclaimed by the OS when the process exits. However, a process can also create memory/resources *globally* as well, and those are not reclaimed until the OS is rebooted, so watch out for that.

Comment: Expanding on @RemyLebeau's remarks: Specifically, some ATOMs are global, and those will not be cleaned up at process exit.

Comment: This may be false-positive reports: if the library holds those resource in some static variables, they could get released after deleaker generates its report.

Comment: Also keep in mind that [atom tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dataxchg/about-atom-tables) are insanely limited in size. Leaking global atoms can quickly cause every other application to fail.